# Multiple types in the same line of output

Tags: python, int, type-conversion, output

My goal is the last print line in the code but i cant really because i keep getting this error `TypeError:` unsupported operand type(s) for +: '`int`' and '`str`'. Is there a quick way to change only the output part to make that possible? I still need them converted to int in the first place but in the case of this output i need to have the words "Population" and "Area" next to ints!

```
def _demo_fileopenbox():        
    msg  = "Pick A File!"
    msg2 = "Select a country to learn more about!"
    title = "Open files"
    default="*.py"
    f = fileopenbox(msg,title,default=default)
    writeln("You chose to open file: %s" % f)    
    countries = {}   

        with open(f,'r') as handle:

        reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter = '\t')  

        for row in reader:

        countries[row[0]] = int(row[1].replace(',', '')), int(row[2].replace(',', ''))

        reply = choicebox(msg=msg2, choices= list(countries.keys()) )

        print(reply)

        print((countries[reply])[0])

        print((countries[reply])[1])

        #print(reply + "- \tArea: + " + (countries[reply])[0] + "\tPopulation: " + (countries[reply])[1] )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to convert them to strings with `str()`:

```
print(reply + "- \tArea: " + str(countries[reply][0]) + "\tPopulation: " + str(countries[reply][1]))
```

Or pass them in as arguments and let `print` take care of it:

```
print(reply + "- \tArea:", countries[reply][0] + "\tPopulation:", countries[reply][1])
```

Although at this point, I would use string formatting:

```
print('{}- \tArea: {}\tPopulation: {}'.format(reply, rountries[reply][0], rountries[reply][1]))
```

Comment: Yea hahah i got it immediately after i posted! `        reply = choicebox(msg=msg2, choices= list(countries.keys()) )
        output = reply + "- \tArea: " + str((countries[reply])[0]) + "\tPopulation: " + str((countries[reply])[1])
        print(output)` thanks for the reply though!

Comment: @erp: You don't need to do `(foo)[0]`. Just write `foo[0]`, without the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the '%' symbol to tell the print line that you are using strings:

```
print(reply + "- \tArea: %s" % countries[reply][0] + "\tPopulation: %s" + % countries[reply][1])
```

Python3 recommends using {:s} in place of %s though. May seem daunting at first, but its not too bad and can be useful.

```
print("{reply}-\tArea: {area}\tPopulation: {population}".format(reply=reply,area=countries[reply][0],population=countries[reply][1]))
```